# How to update a property of an object in an object array at a collection item in mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection schema(as per the example below

```
{ __v: 10,
  _id: 52d43fcfde1899c613000003,
  container: 52d3dedaebbbc0ab73000003,
  name: 'R(25Dec-5Jan).pdf',
  parent: 52d3dedaebbbc0ab73000004,
  reference_url: '/folder=52d3dedaebbbc0ab73000003&folder=52d3dedaebbbc0ab73000004&file=52d43fcfde1899c613000003',
  type: 'Custom',
  uuid: '893e4317-4688-4c2a-9bbb-80a3d0fee9b1',
  signatures:
   [ { __v: 0,
       _id: 52e66f4e7e6c3f9b39a43eb6,
       initiated_by: 52b47058fe5e3493a2cf8365,
       envelope_id: '0731dfc2-533f-4a68-99ed-326b2410684a',
       status: 'signed',
       name: '*********************',
       email: '*************',
       docusign: [Object] },
     { _id: 52e66fa82721b5bd393d7761,
       initiated_by: 52b47058fe5e3493a2cf8365,
       envelope_id: '0738582f-c272-44b7-8ccc-161f1065850e',
       status: 'pending_signature',
       name: '*************',
       email: '************',
       docusign: [Object],
       __v: 0 },
   ]
}
```

How can i update the status of a signature object in the collection item, based on an envelope_id? Also how can i delete one single object from the signatures array based on envelope_id?

Answer (score 1):

As your `signatures` is an array. You can iterate over that and if the match is found for the `envelope_id` do an update or delete. If you do not want to do it manually use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) functions to do it for you.